# Given two arrays find the probability that there is an index i such that A[i]=B[i]!

Tags: arrays, probability

The arrays of size n will have values between ranges 0->n-1....

e.g array of size 30 has values between 0 and 29... No repetitions of values...

I coded the probability and the answer for n=3 (i.e 0,1,2) is .66 and for n=30

is .68

my attempt at a solution is this:

suppose n=30;

finding A[I]=B[I] =j for some values of I and j. the probability is 1/30*1/30... The problem is that since I and j can both go from 1-> 30 the answer should be 1... Which is definitely not the case

Comment: What have you tried?  What, specifically, about this assignment is giving you trouble?  What is your question?

Comment: my attempt at solution was this:

Comment: finding A[I]=B[I] =j  for some values of I and j. the probability is 1/30*1/30... The problem is that sine I and j can both go from 1-> 30 the answer should be 1... Which is definitely not the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is an equivalent question](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/04/06/subfactorial/).

Fun fact:

As n goes to infinity, the probability that there is such an index goes to 1 - 1/e.